# How can I force user to work on particular modal of UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to make some modal like Xbox live login function below.

[Xbox live login modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LscMj.gif)

I tried to use multi-view in Microsoft sample below.
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MultipleViews

[User can switch between modal and windows freely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr0Fk.gif)

But in this case, the user can switch view freely.
How can I force a user to focus on the current view with UWP?

Comment: Just a little note: The UX term for this behavior is "modal" https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12045/what-is-a-modal-dialog-window. Makes googling easier if you don't know the specific class in your current framework.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I've adjusted question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean about ContentDialog?

You can show a content dialog to make the User input something to it and the Main windows dont access any input.

You can watch this video to understand what you want.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Si-z1HsVW4

See:[ContentDialog Class (Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls) - UWP app developer | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog)